# How to resize image in item selector xml

Tags: java, android, xml, checkbox

How to resize item of selector in XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/check_box_2" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/check_box_1" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_box_2" /> <!-- default state -->
</selector>
```

My XML is:

```
<CheckBox
    android:text="llllll"
    android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change it in this manner:

```
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <size android:width="30" android:height="40"/>
        <solid android:color="#000000" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

From API Level 23 and higher, you can actually set the width & height on an item

```
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/splash_logo"
    android:height="100dp"
    android:width="100dp" />
```

NOTE: it's `android:width` instead of `android:layout_width`

**EDIT**

There is however one more way to achieve the same purpose and i.e. by attaching an `xml` accordingly:

**Checked.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android=http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient 
        android:startColor="#ffff0000" 
        android:endColor="#ff000000" 
        android:angle="270" />
    <stroke 
        android:width="4px" 
        android:color="#ffc0c0c0" />
    <size 
        android:height="20dp" 
        android:width="20dp" />
</shape>
```

and then appending it as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@xml/Checked" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/check_box_1" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_box_2" /> <!-- default state -->
</selector>
```

Do notice **Checked** in your `xml` file. You can achieve any purpose by editing it(accordingly)

Comment: My app is use minSdkVersion =19

Comment: Please embed your `xml` code also where these `CheckBoxes` are.